# HBase and Spark - NullPointerException while trying to write to table

Tags: python, apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

I'm using HDP with Ambari on 3 nodes cluster. I tried to save data to Hbase table from Spark using example code ([link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.1/examples/src/main/python/hbase_outputformat.py)) but my job failed.

Command I used:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
--jars spark-examples-1.6.0.2.4.0.0-169-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169.jar,\
hbase-common.jar, hbase-client.jar, hbase-server.jar, hbase-protocol.jar\
example.py 172.16.7.33 test row2 cols q1 value1
```

Error:
[link](http://pastebin.com/wm2c5wt4)

I can run Hbase shell and add rows to table manualy. I think something is wrong with Hbase configuration (RegionServers?). After instalation, Ambari couldn't connect to RegionServers. I restarted Hbase and now it's ok, no alerts.

Can someone help me with it? Thanks.

HBase ver. 1.1.2, Spark ver. 1.6 (both installed via Ambari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the HBase config on your classpath or are you hitting zookeeper by luck since you are on a zookeeper node (localhost)?

We have some examples of Spark Streaming with HBase on our example code site if you are interested.

https://github.com/splicemachine/splice-community-sample-code

Let me know, since you cannot get meta I suspect your configuration is not on the path or hbase does not have regions assigned...

Comment: I have zookeeper on every node. In hbase-site.xml i have them defined. On Hbase Master UI i see my regions and i can connect to their UI. How to config classpath? Adding jars is not enough?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...  The Spark Executor will need the hbase-site.xml in its path.  Try this param spark.executor.extraclasspath...

Comment: Lastly I didn't have time to solve this problem. You was right, I had to give hbase-site.xml to path, but spark.executor.extraclasspath and `--driver-class-path` didn't work for me. I added path to hbase-site.xml via `--jars` and it worked. Thanks!